# How to eliminate duplicates in your results

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have got a query:

```
db.collection.find({time : {$gt:unixTime}}, {productID:1})
```

I am getting a couple of productID duplicates, how I can write a query, so it displays only once?

Comment: use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/index.html#distinct) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mongo's [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) function:

```
db.collection.distinct("productId", {unixxTime : {$lt:unixTime}})
```